# How to set page orientation in PHP Jasper XML

Tags: php, jasper-reports

I have report with width size is bigger than height size (like landscape but set to portrait in Format -> page format ireport). When I preview on ireport, its working fine, but when I load it into PHPJasperXML, it's look portrait not landscape (not same as i report preview). I want set page orientation to portrait with width size is higher than height size. Thanks.

```
public function print($prid) {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();        
    $server=  $CI->db->hostname;
    $db=  $CI->db->database;
    $user=  $CI->db->username;
    $pass= $CI->db->password;
    $xml = base_url('reports/purchase_request.jrxml');        
    $this->load->library('PHPJasperXML');

    $this->phpjasperxml->arrayParameter=array('PRID'=> $prid);
    $this->phpjasperxml->load_xml_file($xml);
    $this->phpjasperxml->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db);
    $this->phpjasperxml->outpage("I");
}
```

This is report loaded with PHPJasperXML:
[image: This is report loaded with PHPJasperXML]

This is preview in ireport:
[image: This is preview in iReport]

Answer (score 1):

**Settings**

When creating the `jrxml` file, you have to provide

```
orientation="Landscape"
```

additionally to all other parameters (like `pageWidth`, `pageHeight` etc.) in the top-level `jasperReport` tag:

```
<jasperReport name="MyReport" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" ...
```

**Rotating**

It is *not* possible to rotate the page by simply setting `pageWidth` and `pageHeight` to values suitable for landscape. PHPJasperXML will check also for `orientation`, as I've seen in the [source code](https://github.com/BBFMedia/PHPJasperXML/blob/master/class/PHPJasperXML.inc.php#L236).

Then PHPJasperXML will interpret this and print the page correctly.

**EDIT**

Just to make it more clear: PHPJasperXML provides no function to rotate a page. The report has to provide its orientation.

Comment: So, how can I set page orientation in my php code above. I want set to portrait

Comment: PHPJasperXML only interprets the `jrxml` file. It is not possible to "overrule" this setting. Also there is no function in PHPJasperXML to set the orientation. You *have* to change the report `jrxml` file.